# Allow both single tap gesture recognizer and double tap in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

So I have an UIImageView inside of a UIScrollView, I need to capture both:
- single tap gesture
- double tap gesture
for the UIImageView

The double tap gesture is supposed to be sent to the UIScrollView as an action of zooming
The single tap gesture is captured by a UITapGestureRecognizer that I created myself.
The double tap gesture has higher priority than the single tap (when there is a double tap, zoom in the scrollview, else perform the single tap)

So far if I add the single tap gesture recognizer to the scrollview, the single tap is immediately recognized and no double tap can be recognized.

If I add the single tap gesture recognizer to the imageview, it never receives any action, but double tap works

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this code,

**Objective - C**

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *singletap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                     initWithTarget:self
                                                     action:@selector(singleTap:)];
    singletap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singletap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singletap];


UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self
                                                 action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired =2 ;
doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];



[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
var singletap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.singleTap))
singletap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singletap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singletap)
var doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.doubleTap))
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
singleTap.require(toFail: doubleTap)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizerForSingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapAction:)];
[tapRecognizerForSingleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizerForDoubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapAction:)];
[tapRecognizerForDoubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
```

Both are added in a same image view and to achieve what you want just add the below line.

```
[tapRecognizerForSingleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapRecognizerForDoubleTap];
```

By the above line you are asking for single tap will be only recognise if it's not double tap.

Comment: but the tap recognizer for double tap is the internal one of uiscrollview, is that still valid to do?

Comment: I just tried `[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:_scrollView.gestureRecognizers[0]];`

and the program crashed..