# Double tap in UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

My project has a custom uitableviewCell which has a image slider inside. basically a scrollview with images paginated.

I need to tap and double tap this ImageSlider to perform some actions. The single tap is working fine, but the double tap selector is not triggered.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(singleTap(_:)))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    slideShowView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)


    //Double tap recognizer
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTap(_:)))
    doubleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

    slideShowView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)

    singleTap.require(toFail: doubleTap)

    print("slideshow recognizers",slideShowView.gestureRecognizers!) }         


func doubleTap(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {

     print("doubletap")        
}

 func singleTap(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {

     print("singleTap")
}
```

regards

EDIT : you can see my Log here, i changed my original post too

```
 slideshow recognizers [<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x17ec1670; state = Possible; view = <ImageSlideshow.ImageSlideshow 0x17ec0e30>; target= <(action=singleTap:, target=<Descubra.FeedDefaultCell 0x183cf800>)>; must-fail = {
    <UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x17e763b0; state = Possible; view = <ImageSlideshow.ImageSlideshow 0x17ec0e30>; target= <(action=doubleTap:, target=<Descubra.FeedDefaultCell 0x183cf800>)>; numberOfTapsRequired = 2>
}>, <UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x17e763b0; state = Possible; view = <ImageSlideshow.ImageSlideshow 0x17ec0e30>; target= <(action=doubleTap:, target=<Descubra.FeedDefaultCell 0x183cf800>)>; numberOfTapsRequired = 2; must-fail-for = {
    <UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x17ec1670; state = Possible; view = <ImageSlideshow.ImageSlideshow 0x17ec0e30>; target= <(action=singleTap:, target=<Descubra.FeedDefaultCell 0x183cf800>)>>
}>]

singleTap
```

Comment: requireToFail is a must if you use two gestures on the same view. also make sure that your view hase userinteractionenabled = YES and that you have no methods in tableview DidSelect that prevents the doubletap from being fired.

Comment: @sneak it has userInteractionEnabled = true, otherwise i couldn't slide my pictures in the slideshow, and the singletap is working, because im opening each picture in another view.

Comment: Sorry I missed the part of you having a UIScrollView . It is much easier if you write UIScrollView in your text in future questions people will miss out on details. Is seems that the ScrollView has its own method for Double Tapping and thats why it fails with your custom one. Try setting delaysContentTouches = NO on the scrollview and let me know if that solves your problem. Otherwise now that you know the problem you can google a solution for it much easier. GL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow both single tap gesture recognizer and double tap in UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298567/allow-both-single-tap-gesture-recognizer-and-double-tap-in-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a single and double tap gesture work together, the system, upon seeing a single, needs to know if it's really a single or the first half of a double.  It must either have knowledge of the future (which would be a very valuable feature) or it must wait and see what comes next.  To tell it to wait and see...

```
singleTap.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTap)
```

Comment: thx for the reply, but as you can see in my code i already tried that, its commented //singleTap.require(toFail: doubleTap) (swift 3 version). it didnt work

Comment: @pneves - sorry.  missed the comment.  hmm.  can you get rid of cancelsTouchesInView=false for both, or did you try that as well?

Comment: @pneves - the gesture code looks proper, so I wonder if it's something more subtle.  This is a tableview cell subclass, right?   Are you using registerClass: or registerNib: when you register it with the table view?  In either case, you should probably use the designated initializer for this code (initWithStyle for registerClass or initWithCoder for registerNib).  awakeFromNib won't be called (I think) when using registerClass.  I'd be more confident about all of this if you were seeing *no* touch behavior.

Comment: yes it is a tableview cell subclass. i register the nib in my delegate controller  self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "FeedDefaultCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: kDefaultCellID). The singleTap method is being called, so i dont think it has any problem with that

Comment: Just to indulge me, in the posted method, after adding the gr's, NSLog the `slideShowView.gestureRecognizers`.  Is it what you expect?

Comment: ok i finally discovered my problem. it seems my Slideshowview library already had a double tap gesture to Zoom that i didn´t notice and was disabled by default. Anyway im going to accept your answer because this is the correct way to do it, and may be helpful to anyone